# Access to Facebook users online statuses: web or mobile?

Tags: facebook, api

I can see my friends are online via mobile or via web browser in the right sidebar Facebook website. Can I get this statuses through the API (online web or mobile)? Can I get these statuses for users who are not my friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for this. You can´t even get the online status of the authorized user anymore:

> user_online_presence is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions